# TypeError: seed is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, seed

I am currently working on an assignment that involves a traveler website and creating a database that stores things like code, name, and length. I am trying to seed data into a database, but I am getting an error that says:

```
    TypeError: seed is not a function
    at main (C:\Users\marce\src\travlr\app_server\models\db.js:30:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
C:\Users\marce\src\travlr\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:972
    throw new MongooseError('Connection.prototype.close() no longer accepts a callback');
```

I thought I installed seedgoose using my terminal. What could be the problem? Here is part of my code:

db.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const host = process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const conn_uri = `mongodb://${host}/travlr`;

const {seed} = require('./seed');

// Register models
require('./trips');

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => console.log('CONNECTED!'));
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => console.log(err));
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => console.log('DISCONNECTED!'));

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

// Kill MongoDB connections before exiting app
const gracefulShutdown = (msg, callback) => {
    mongoose.connection.close( () => {
        console.log(`Mongoose disconnected due to ${msg}`);
        callback();
    });
}
process.once('SIGUSR2', () =>
    gracefulShutdown('nodemon restart', () => process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2')));
process.on('SIGINT', () =>
    gracefulShutdown('app termination', () => process.exit(0)));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect(conn_uri);
    await seed();
}

main().catch(console.log);
```

seed.js

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const seed = async function() {
    // Seed TRIPS 
    const trips = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(_dirname, '../../data/trips.json'), 'utf8'));
    const trip = mongoose.model('trips');
    await trip.deleteMany();
    await trip.insertMany(trips);

    module.exports = { seed };
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `seed` module (either `seed.js` or `seed/index.js`)

Comment: I just added seed.js @Phil

Comment: `module.exports = { seed };` should go after the `}` of the function

Comment: That fixed the seed problem. Now I am getting a ReferenceError saying _dirname is not defined

Comment: Adding another underscore fixed the dirname problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moving the module.exports = { seed }; outside of the function scope helped and adding another underscore to _dirname helped.

```
    const seed = async function() {
    // Seed TRIPS 
    const trips = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../data/trips.json'), 'utf8'));
    const trip = mongoose.model('trips');
    await trip.deleteMany();
    await trip.insertMany(trips);

}

module.exports = { seed };
```